# Is There a Difference Between The Disk Cache and The Disk Write Cache?

Tags: windows-7, cache

I just want to make sure that by attempting to increase my Disk Cache, I am not delaying Write cache flushes to happen any later than they are now.

If the Disk cache and Disk Write cache are two seperate entities I guess the "LargeSystemCache" key does not affect the Disk Write cache? And the Disk Cache is only for caching reads?

Comment: There isn't really a single proper noun called "The Disk Cache" so we need you to clarify whether you are refering to IO subsystem caching as described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364218(v=vs.85).aspx , or software features like readyboost: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReadyBoost or somthing else entirely. There are many types of caches and strategies for caching, and knowing exactly which ones you mean is critical. this may help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742613.aspx

Comment: The IOCache, when a file gets paged off the disk and cached into RAM.